# Updating model field by adding old value to new Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to keep track of the total hours being put into a work order. I'd like to add the new number being entered to the number existing in the DB and return the total.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
The Model:
class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hours_worked = models.IntegerField()

The View:
class UpdateWorkOrder(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = WorkOrder
    template_name = 'client/update_workorder.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this method to the view:

```
    def get_form_class(self):
        work_order = WorkOrder.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0] # Get the previous latest object here
        new_hours = work_order.hours_worked + self.object.hours_worked
        self.object.hours_worked = new_hours
```

OR

You can add the same code to pre `save` method to model.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the last value does not add hours to the specified client. If you entered:

- id = 5, hours_worked = 10, client = Jane
- id = 6, hours_worked = 10, client = Ann,

then you will add hours only to the last id which is 6, so to Ann only.

If you want to add hours depending on the selected id I'd do this in models in that way:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id:
        work_order = WorkOrder.objects.get(id=self.id)
        self.hours_worked = work_order.hours_worked + self.hours_worked
    super(WorkOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```